# Site-to-Site VPN from Windows Azure to Cyberoam CR25iNG

Tags: ipsec, azure, site-to-site-vpn, vpn

I'm trying to configure Site-to-Site VPN between **Windows Azure** and on Premise network using **Cyberoam CR25iNG UTM** Firewall

The **Local Network** Subnet is

```
192.168.0.1/20 (192.168.0.0 - 192.168.15.255)
```

The Address Space of Azure is

```
192.168.16.0/20 (192.168.16.4 - 192.168.31.254)
```

The following subnets have been created on Windows Azure

```
FrontEndSubnet 192.168.18.0/24 (192.168.18.4 - 192.168.18.254)
BackEndSubnet  192.168.20.0/24 (192.168.20.4 - 192.168.20.254)
ADDNSSubnet    192.168.22.0/24 (192.168.22.4 - 192.168.22.254)
Gateway        192.168.16.0/24 (192.168.16.4 - 192.168.16.254)
```

I've followed the instructions on

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/cross-premises-connectivity/

I've got a valid Gateway address and managed to generate a Pre-Shared key.

On the Cyberoam gateway, I've setup an IPSEC VPN connection entering the gateway details and configuring the subnets as follows:

```
Local Network: 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0

Remote Network: 192.168.16.0/255.255.240.0
```

Cant manage to connect from the Azure Side or the Local Network.

Azure only has scripts for Cisco, Juniper and Microsoft RRAS.

Anybody managed to use **Cyberoam** to connect with Azure VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cyberoam has given the solution for firmware 10.0 onwards. The detailed explanation is given on this URL
http://kb.cyberoam.com/default.asp?id=2936&Lang=1

Comment: Your link doesn't say _anything_ about firmware. Did you post the wrong link by mistake?